# ssh config is working from home, but not working from another directory

Tags: ssh, gitolite

I could solve my problem, but I'm pretty curious why it isn't working the way it should be.

The problem:
In `~/.ssh/config` there is an entry:

```
Host git
HostName git.myserver.com
User gitolite
Identityfile gitolite
```

After that in my home directory when I run: `ssh git` it returns this text (which is a normal thing):

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

hello myname, this is gitolite@myserver.com running gitolite3 v3.4-3-g797a81f on git 1.7.2.5

 R W    myrepo1
 R W    myrepo2
 R W    .
 R W    .
 R W    .
Connection to git.myserver.com closed.
```

But when I'm running `ssh git` from my `/opt/poky` directory, it cannot authenticate me with my file... or I don't know what's the problem, but the result is:

```
gitolite@myserver.com's password:
```

Most interesting is when I'm changing my `.git/config's` `url` variable from `git:poky` to `gitolite@git.myserver.com:poky` then everything works fine.

It seems more an ssh issue than a gitolite.

Could it be some environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config file should contain, to be sure, the full path of your private/public key:

```
Identityfile /path/to/gitolite
```

Beside that, make sure `$HOME` is the same in both cases, and that you are running those commands with the same user id, to rule out any right access.

> Most interesting is when I'm changing my `.git/config's` `url` variable from `git:poky` to `gitolite@git.myserver.com:poky` then everything works fine.

That means your public/private key (named `~/.ssh/gitolite(.pub)`) is duplicated as `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`, which is the default name for those keys, as searched by ssh.