# Git clone produces bad packet length error

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have trouble pulling a git repository via ssh on Windows.  The repository is on a GitLab Server. I do the following steps:

1. create a public key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@email.here"`
2. save the keys in `C:\Users\myUserName\.ssh\keyName`
3. run the output of `ssh-agent` (i.e. export SSH_AUTH_SOCK; ...)
4. run `ssh-add` and add the key in `C:\Users\myUserName\.ssh\keyName`
5. add the public key in GitLab.

**The same setup works fine on my Linux and on the Windows machines of my colleagues.**
When i try to clone a repository with `git clone` I get the following error:

`Disconnecting: Bad packet length 1397966893.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

I tried to google it, but i found nothing appropriate. Does somebody know if i may have made a mistake or that the bug may be server-side?

EDIT:I get the following debug output:

```
C:\Users\Johannes\Documents\GitHub> ssh -vT -p 80 git@random.secret.sever.de
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Johannes/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to random.secret.sever.de [192.44.1.37] port 80.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Johannes/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Johannes/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Johannes/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Disconnecting: Bad packet length 1397966893.
```

EDIT 2: Looks like my problem is based in my hard- and software setup. Just did the same steps in parallel and it worked on the other computer.

Comment: Have you verified the general connection to gitlab? (If not you can issue this command: `ssh git@gitlab.com`)

Comment: I get the following output: `Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.com,54.243.197.170' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Then you need to add YOUR public key to YOUR GitLab Account.

Comment: Then your local ssh setup is not configured correctly.

Comment: i did that in 5) - fingerprints are also matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause for my problem by accident. I tried to use an old trick and started a System Recovery to undo my Git installation. It failed because of my Virus Scanner. After uninstalling *Bitdefender Antivirus Free Edition*  it worked. Incoming SSH2 messages were blocked (got Windows 8 Pro) which caused the `bad packet length` error. Anyway, thanks for your support!

Comment: Good feedback, more precise than my initial answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

> save the keys in `C:\Users\myUserName\.ssh\keyName`

Your local ssh command would look for ssh keys in `%HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)`.

So you need to either:

- rename the local files representing your ssh (public and private) keys
- or reference those through a `%HOME%\.ssh\config` which can reference the exact name of your private key (with an [`IdentityFile` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16897818/6309)).

  ```
  Host gitlab 
  user git
  hostname your.gitlab.server.com
  IdentityFile C:\user\YourUsername\.ssh\keyName
  ```

In the second case, the ssh url would be `gitlab:yourRepo`.

Comment: I would be nice if you could take a look at my edit, maybe this will clarify my problem. The name of my in Gitlab registred key is id_rsa. Thank in advance

Comment: @joschuck by "name" I am only talking about the file name in your local computer, not the name of the ssh key as registered in the GitLab instance.

Comment: Excuse me, that's what i meant, i have a bad grammar.