# access repository with ssh

Tags: git, ssh

Yesterday I found out about existence of such thing as git.I need to access a remote repository with ssh.I used command `$ git clone git@forest.com:stranger@gmail.com`. But when I use this , it says it's cloning and then requires a password. Though I have secret and pub keys in ~/.ssh.And also I have a config file, that looks like this:

```
Host forest
    User git
    HostName forest.com
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<stranger@gmail.com>.key
```

Can you ppl give me a tip, how can I access this remote repository and why I need this config file, and what can I do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your key has no standard name, you need to use your config file.
But the exact url for that would be:

```
git clone forest:yourRepo
```

The key "`forest`" reference the Host entry in your `~/.ssh/config` file, which will provide ssh with the right user, hostname, port and private key file to use.

`YourRepo` should be the name or the full path of the repo you want to clone.
I doubt your repo is named `stranger@gmail.com`.

---

The other issues are:

- **the name of the config file**:
  no extension needed: **`~/.ssh/config`** only. Anything else will be ignored by ssh.
- **the name of your private key**:
  I strongly suggests avoiding the '`@`' in it, and **using a full path**: `/home/myName/.ssh/myKey` and `/home/myName/.ssh/myKey.pub` (for private and public keys).
  Then your `IdentityFile` should reference the key **without any extension**: `/home/myName/.ssh/myKey`: that is the private one (as opposed to the public one: `/home/myName/.ssh/myKey.pub`).

Comment: When I do this, the following things that I get are: "no address associated with name" from ssh and then fatal "couln't read from repository"

Comment: @user3130843 is your config file in the right place? `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: I added it in 2 places ~/.ssh/config.txt and ~/.ssh/config/config.txt to make sure, is this wrong?

Comment: @user3130843 I confirm: no extension needed: `~/.ssh/config` only. Anything else **will be ignored** by ssh.

Comment: So there shouldn't be any other problems?

Comment: @user3130843 see examples of that approach used in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9633439/6309, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/9551540/6309, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/16897818/6309

Comment: @user3130843 the other issue is the name of your private key. I strongly suggests avoiding the '@' in it, and using a full path: `/home/myName/.ssh/myKey` and `/home/myName/.ssh/myKey.pub` (for private and public keys). Then your  IdentityFile should reference the key **without any extension**: `/home/myName/.ssh/myKey`: that is **the private one** (as opposed to the public one: `/home/myName/.ssh/myKey.pub`)

Comment: I'll think about your words, cause it still doesn't work.But to be sure, could the problem be, that the path to keys are in non-latin symbols?

Comment: @user3130843 sure: it is better if the path is a standard one, with standard characters. And no '@' anywhere.

Comment: @user3130843 any time. I have edited the answer to include the issues detected so far, for more visibility.