# Git push over SSH on Windows won't work

Tags: windows, git, ssh, msysgit

I've got an enigma for you guys!

After an half a day struggle on this issue, I require your experience to enlighten me on git usage on Windows with msysgit.

**The context:**

- **Windows 8**
- **msysgit**, last version
- Using **SSH** Key authentication
- **Pagent** handles SSH key authentication using valid *.ppk* key (logon with PuTTY is OK)
- The **bare repository is healthy**, with permissions OK. Working with git linux client (tested on local Ubuntu VM with the same SSH key)

**Env:**

- GIT_SSH=D:\path\to\PuTTY\plink.exe
- HOME=C:\path\to\myself

**The issue:**

Short:

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./obj
```

Long:

```
D:\path\to>git clone ssh://git@my.server.net/opt/git/project
Cloning into 'project'...
Unable to use key file "D:\path\to\puttykey.ppk" (unable to open file)
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

D:\path\to>cd project

...me creating some random file...

D:\path\to\project>git add test

D:\path\to\project>git commit -m "Init"
[master 118a94e] Init
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test

D:\path\to\project>git push origin master
Unable to use key file "D:\path\to\puttykey.ppk" (unable to open file)
Counting objects: 2, done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 293 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 2 (delta 1)
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./obj

fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To ssh://git@my.server.net/opt/git/project
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@my.server.net/opt/git/project'
```

I'm honestly accepting any kind of help, thanks by advance..!

By the way, what the hell with this `Unable to use key file "D:\path\to\puttykey.ppk"`??

Comment: Would this particular answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15319683/6309

Comment: ... you spotted it wonderfully, million thanks, I love you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the answers, as the ones in "[Error pushing to GitHub - insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1918524/6309)" mentions an issue around access rights in folder.
That translates into chmod... which doesn't really apply on Windows.

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15319683/6309) mentions the *same* error message when your ssh url reference an entry in your `%HOME%/.ssh/config` file which is for another public/private ssh key than the one you want to use.

Make sure your url uses the right entry, as I explain in "[access repository with ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22579676/6309)"

```
Host aKey
    User git
    HostName yourHost
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<stranger@gmail.com>.key
```

Here, the [OP blint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2219133/blint) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035302/git-push-over-ssh-on-windows-wont-work/23035735?noredirect=1#comment35193283_23035735):

> the message `Unable to use key file "D:\path\to\puttykey.ppk"` was therefore **due to a wrong path defined in the incriminated PuTTY profile**.

Comment: In order to complete the answer: the message `Unable to use key file "D:\path\to\puttykey.ppk"` was therefore due to a wrong path defined in the incriminated PuTTY profile.

Comment: @blint Ok. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.